# Convert Unix Timestamp - Spotfire Analyst

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I'm importing SQL data into Spotfire Analyst. All of the date and time fields are in the form of a Unix timestamp. What's the best way to convert this into an actual date format that I can manipulate in Spotfire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizing a calculated column you can calculate the datetime based on the UNIX epoch.

We simply add our seconds to the DateTime of the UNIX epoch (JAN 01 1970 00:00:00 UTC) to get the result. Below is an example of the UNIX time when I started writing this post.

```
DateAdd("second",1429733486,DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0))
```

The below is what should work for you:

```
DateAdd("second",[UNIX_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN],DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0))
```

Keep in mind these dates produced will be in the UTC timezone as per the JAN 1 1970 epoch. If you need them in your local time zone you may have to adjust accordingly with further DateAdd functions adding/subtracting time as per current conversions. Also, if you observe daylight savings time you may need to add some extra case logic to handle that as well.

Please let me know if you have any questions or need further clarification.

Comment: Is there some way I can leverage a UDF on the SQL side? There's a lot of date/time columns I'd have to do this for.

Comment: In a similar logic format you could change it in your SQL select statement to do some basic math with the epoch. Adding to dates in SQL (Oracle SQL at least) is done in terms of days. E.g. Sysdate-1 is yesterday. So we can add our UNIX timestamp divied by (60*60*24) [secs/min * min/hour * hours/day] and turn that into a string with to_char:

`select to_char(to_date('01/01/1970','mm/dd/yyyy')+1429733486/86400) 
from dual`

You can replace 1429733486 with your column in question and set up each column like this in your SQL.

Comment: @ILoveYou  Note, if your unixepoch column value is too big you may need to convert it to a Real first.  I had to that in ours because the column was BigInteger type is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

In 7.0 and later you can use

```
FromEpohTimeSeconds([UNIXDATE])
```

or

```
FromEpohTimeMilliseconds([UNIXDATE])
```